# Fetch several ParseObjects with objectId

Tags: swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am updating an iOS app using ParseSwift. In general, every ParseUser of the app has several associated Userdata ParseObjects that need to be queried or fetched.

The current implementation uses individual queries to find every individual Userdata object one after the other. This works but is obviously not optimal.

What I already reworked is that every ParseUser now saves an Array of objectId's of the user-associated Userdata ParseObjects.

What I am trying to achieve now is to query for all Userdata objects that correspond to these saved objectId's in the ParseUser's userdataIds field.

This is my code:

```
func asyncAllUserdataFromServer() {
    let userdataIdArray = User.current!.userdataIds

    var objectsToBeFetched = [Userdata]()

    userdataIdArray?.forEach({ objectId in
        let stringObjectId = objectId as String
            
        // create a dummy Userdata ParseObject with stringObjectId
        let object = Userdata(objectId: stringObjectId)
            
        // add that object to array of Userdata objects that need to be fetched
        objectsToBeFetched.append(object)
    })
        
    // fetch all objects in one server request
    objectsToBeFetched.fetchAll { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let fetchedData):
            
        // --- at this point, fetchedData is a ParseError ---
        // --- here I want to loop over all fetched Userdata objects ---

        case .failure(let error):
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I read in the ParseSwift documentation that several objects can be fetched at the same time based on their objectIds, so my idea was to create an Array of dummy Userdata objects with the objectIds to fetch. This, however, does not work.

As indicated in the code block, I was able to narrow the error down, and while the query is executed, `fetchedData` comes back as a `ParseError` saying:

`Error fetching individual object: ParseError code=101 error=objectId "y55wmfYTtT" was not found in className "Userdata"`

This Userdata object with that objectId is the first (and only) objectId saved in the User.current.userdataIds array. This object does exist on my server, I know that for sure.

Any ideas why it cannot be fetched?

General infos:

- Xcode 13.2.1
- Swift 5
- ParseSwift 2.5.0
- Back4App backend

Edit:

User implementation:

```
struct User: ParseUser {

    //: These are required by `ParseObject`.
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?

    //: These are required by `ParseUser`.
    var username: String?
    var email: String?
    var emailVerified: Bool?
    var password: String?
    var authData: [String: [String: String]?]?

    //: Custom keys.
    var userdataIds: [String]?  // --> array of Userdata objectId's

}
```

Userdata implementation:

```
struct Userdata: ParseObject, ParseObjectMutable {
    
    var objectId: String?
    var createdAt: Date?
    var updatedAt: Date?
    var ACL: ParseACL?
    
    var firstname: String?
    var lastSeen: Int64?
    var isLoggedIn: Bool?
    var profilepicture: ParseFile?
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your [Class Level Permissions (CLP's)](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#class-level-permissions) and [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#class-level-permissions) in Parse Dashboard, if you are using the default configuration, you can’t query the `_User` class unless you make the CLP’s public or authorized. In addition, you can probably shrink your code by using a query and finding the objects instead of building your user objects and fetching the way you are doing:

```swift
let userdataIdArray = User.current!.userdataIds
let query = Userdata.query(containedIn(key: "objectId", array: userdataIdArray))

//Completion block
query.find { result in
  switch result {
  case .success(let usersFound):
    ...
  case .failure(let error):
    ...
  }
}

// Async/await
do {
  let usersFound = try await query.find()
  ...
} catch {
  ...
}
```

You should also look into your server settings to make sure this option is doing what you want it to do: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/4c29d4d23b67e4abaf25803fe71cae47ce1b5957/src/Options/docs.js#L31

Comment: Hey Corey, I just tried it with the query that you described instead of fetching and now it works like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Just one follow-up question regarding performance: I wanted to use fetch because I thought it is always faster to fetch than to query. Is this correct or do both ways have a similar performance? (at least in this example)

Comment: Since you were using `fetchAll`, it's using the same find query anyways, so they both have the same performance: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/e6c2db2f316d4c8a5954e342455359f7d854195a/Sources/ParseSwift/Objects/ParseObject.swift#L481-L486. You can use either. Performance will be dependent on your DB (Postgres or Mongo). `objectId` has a default index, so you should be okay there

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the Object Ids for UserData are the same as the User ids? while you might have user id in the class, it is probably not the objectId, but some other stored field.

doing

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"UserData")
query.whereKey("userId", containedIn:userdataIdArray)
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
// do stuff
}
```

May help.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your input. I am positive that the userdataId array of the ParseUser corresponds to the actual objectId's of the Userdata ParseObjects. My code example above tries to fetch one Userdata object that was created upon signup: After signing up the ParseUser, a Userdata object was created, saved to the server, and this newly created Userdata object's objectId was then saved to the ParseUser's userdataId array.

Comment: I assume your code works with the Parse-SDK. Since I am using the ParseSwift SDK I am not sure how to translate your code example. I have experience with the Android SDK and your code looks like how I implemented this behaviour in the Android version of the app, but for the iOS version I decided to pursue a full Swift implementation.

Comment: Have you checked out this link: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/api/Protocols/QueryObservable.html#/s:10ParseSwift15QueryObservableP5queryxAA0C0Vy6ObjectQzG_tcfc

I don't have time to write up fully working syntax anymore. Also it may be helpful to post a picture of your class structure for User and Userdata

Comment: I will update my question with my ParseUser and Userdata implementation.

Comment: So, sorry for the dumb question but just. confirming. you have double checked you have a Userdata with exactly that id

Comment: No worries, yes, I just checked it again. My User has an associated Userdata object with objectId y55wmfYTtT, and this objectId is saved in my User object in the String array userdataIds.

Comment: Sorry, if this last comment is unhelpful, but I'm genuinely stumped then. The code written should work. My only guess is that somewhere a field or class name may be misspelled or some oversight was made somewhere: without being able to see everything maybe the class name is UserData or something. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your input anyway, I appreciate the effort Patrick!